# Insert Function Postgresql how to test with parameters?

Tags: postgresql, function

I have the following insert function in postgresql 9.4.
I am totally unable to test it with parameters.

```
DROP FUNCTION "Public".cash_inserts(integer, bigint, timestamp without time zone, character varying, numeric, numeric);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Public".cash_inserts(
cashid integer,
cashserial bigint,
cashdate timestamp without time zone,
cashmemo text,
cashcredit numeric,
cashdebit numeric)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$ 

INSERT INTO "Public"."CashAccounts"
VALUES
    (
        CashId,
        CashSerial,
        CashDate,
        CashMemo,
        CashCredit,
        CashDebit
    ) RETURNING CashId ; 

 $BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

ALTER FUNCTION "Public".cash_inserts(integer, bigint, timestamp without time zone, text, numeric, numeric)
  OWNER TO robert100;
```

Because the fields 'cashid,cashserial,cashdate' are either auto-incrementing or created by the database, I did not enter any values. However, Cashmemo is'Not NUll' and 'Cashcredit,Cashdebit' are nullable or optional.

Answer (score 0):

Why include cashid,cashserial,cashdate in the function insert statement if they are `either auto-incrementing or created by the database` as you said and the function returns int?

Maybe try:

```
DROP FUNCTION "Public".cash_inserts(integer, bigint, timestamp without time zone, character varying, numeric, numeric);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Public".cash_inserts(
cashmemo text,
cashcredit numeric,
cashdebit numeric)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$ INSERT INTO "Public"."CashAccounts"
VALUES
    (
        CashMemo,
        CashCredit,
        CashDebit
    ) RETURNING CashId ; $BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION "Public".cash_inserts(text, numeric, numeric)
  OWNER TO robert100
```

Then call the function with the variable parameters and cashid, cashserial and cashdate will be auto generated by the database.

Comment: [Err] ERROR:  column "CashId" is of type integer but expression is of type text
LINE 9:         CashMemo,
                ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Answer (score 0):

It appears my original question was correct.What I discovered is that when you supply parameters, they must all be in quotes like this:

```
    SELECT "Public".cash_inserts(
    '10',
    '4',
    '12-12-12',
    'COOL',
    '200',
    '300'
);
```